# Trying to create a conditional CSS snippet based on user role

Tags: css, wordpress, roles

Basically what I’m trying to do is to remove an element using CSS for a peculiar user role. I tried the following snippet, but no luck.

```
$user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( in_array( 'customer', (array) $user->roles ) ) {
 add_action( 'wp_head', function () { ?>
<style>
.CSSselector: {display: none;}
</style>
<?php } );}
```

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: What is the exact name of your class, CCSselector: or CSSselector ?

Comment: Should this question have a php tag? Can you look at the HTML and CSS that has been created (using your browser's dev tools inspect facility)? It is unusual to have a selector with a colon, are you replacing that with your own selector?

Comment: Actually I am using the Snippet Code plugin which is on the the Wordpress repository and the CSS snippet example that is included in it when you look at the snippet list.

Comment: Actually I am using the Snippet Code plugin which is on the the Wordpress repository and the CSS snippet example that is included in it when you look at the snippet list. This snippet does work. Integrating the user role condition in it is the issue I am facing. The CSS class is inventory.dokan-edit-row
 add_action( 'wp_head', function () {
 ?>
 <style>
.CSSselector {display: none;}
 </style>
 <?php
} );